# How can I read the dmp file created by perfmon?

Tags: iis, performance, performance-monitoring, perfmon

I'm trying to debug a memory problem on a client web server that I have no access to.  The client, with some help from Microsoft consulting, set up a bunch of perfmon counters and just sent us the results, in the form of a massive (750MB) binary file with a .dmp extension, and I have no idea how to read this file.

windbg is the only tool I can find for dmp files, but that's about stack frames and crashes, not log data.  perfmon itself doesn't seem to know what to do with this file.

It's entirely possible that the client messed this up, but I'm on the hook to make some sense of this file.  Can anyone advise what this dmp file is and how to read it?

Comment: Are you sure this is a perfmon and not a kernel dump? .BLP is usually a perfmon export, and .dmp is usually a crash dump extension.

To be sure, download 'Debugging tools for Windows' and confirm by using the 'open crash dump' menu item.   If it opens properly, they sent you a crash dump and not perfmon output.

Comment: You are correct; they sent us the wrong file.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grr, sorry to bother everyone.  They sent us the wrong file, and that explains the mystery.  Please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

There's a microsoft KB article specifically for this: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/183399

Comment: My problem is that I don't have a .log file, I have a .dmp file.  I am starting to think that they just sent me the wrong file, because perfmon seems like it couldn't possibly have created one of these.